# "Add User" option not displayed for specific user

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I need help regarding SharePoint.

I have two users (UserA and UserB) that are in a same group (GroupA) that has full control on the application. This means, they can add new users.

However, when UserA logs in, the option "Add User" is not seen. However when UserB logs in, that option is displayed.

Any ideas where I can check this?

Answer (score 0):

Run `inetmgr` and select your application and right click select permissions and check. For further checking you could go for advanced tab.